# Using the columnA value to update columnB while also updating columnA in the same statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For example:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Column1 = Column2, Column2 = Column3
```

Is this guaranteed to always result in an update like this:

before:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 200 | 3000 |

after:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 3000 | 3000 |

A quick experimentation suggests it works, but I couldn't find anything on MSDN that definitively says it would.

Comment: All changes are persisted at the same time, not column by column.

Comment: You can even do `UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = Column2, Column2 = Column1` to swap the column values.

Comment: It's supposed to work that way, the technique to handle this is called `halloween protection/problem` which ensures the values aren't changed from underneath you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the result will be as desired. SQL Server performs the update as a set-based operation so the update logically happens all at once. One can even reverse the column order to achieve the same results:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = Column2, Column2 = Column3;
UPDATE Table1 SET Column2 = Column3, Column1 = Column2;
```

Comment: Thank you! "set-based" was the term I was looking for and could not for the life of me recall. An internet search is difficult if you can't phrase your question properly :)

Comment: Interesting you've accepted this answer just on the word of someone without a reference :)

Comment: @Dale K That was because the answer reminded me of the term I needed to have the conversation I needed to have! Reference I used to verify was on my bookshelf: Fundamentals of Database Systems, Elmasri & Navathe, 2nd Edition, p 157-160, discussion of set theory in relational databases. ( old college text book! )

It appears that the seventh edition can be found online: https://amirsmvt.github.io/Database/Static_files/Fundamental_of_Database_Systems.pdf

Looks like it is Chapter 8 that addresses the issue in that edition.